# Winform dialog show modal form wait for Dialogresult

Tags: winforms, ironpython

I need to use "Show()" method for dialog winform using Ironpython
and i need to get result of button pressing and use it in another part of program
how can i wait for pressing OK in modal "Show()" dialog?

```
mform = Form3()
mform.Show()
# How to wait for button OK
```

Thx

Comment: `mform.ShowDialog()` is what  you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use ShowDialog() instead of Show().
Then check "if (mform.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)"

Comment: But i need especially "Show()" form because it is modal.
Or maybe is it possible run ShowDialog() in thread?

Comment: @DmitryDronov I don't follow your reasoning of why `ShowDialog()` won't work. You either want to wait for the dialog to close or not. If you do use `ShowDialog()` and if you don't use `Show()`. It is that simple.

Comment: I need to get possibility that program can work in modal mode but give me dialogresult

Comment: What do you think is _modal mode_?

Comment: You can get a dialogresult on any kind of form (modal or not). Just creat a DialogResult variable on the form class and set it to a default value, then on buttons click or on form closing, set it as needed. Maybe you want to take a look at "TopMost" property also...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a main form called `Form1` and a secondary form called `AddForm` which presents some result when the [OK] button is pressed.

The main form then can subscribe to the `FormClosed` event of the secondary form and pull the result if the user clicked on the [OK] button.

This can all happen in the subroutine where the secondary form is shown

```
Private Sub Button1.Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim dlg as New AddForm
  AddHandler dlg.FormClosed, _
    Sub(e,ev) TextBox1.Text = If(dlg.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK, dlg.Result, String.Empty)
  dlg.Show() 
End Sub
```

And in the secondary form make sure there is a property called `Result` which contains the results

The [OK] button has a handler like so

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Result = ...
  DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
  Me.Close()
End Sub
```

and the [Cancel] button has a handler as so

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
  Me.Close()
End Sub
```